# can I migrate .NET Framework 4.6.1 to 4.7.2 only if change web config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, migrate

I have already deployed website and API in .NET

```
targetFramework="4.6.2".
```

This app is hosted in IIS.

As `Framework="4.6.2"` will be no longer supported by Microsoft after 26 April 2022, I need to update from 4.6.2 to 4.7.2.

Note: I don't have source code of application to rebuild the solution.
so I only changed in config file in IIS

Current:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <!--... many other things -->
</system.web>
```

Updated:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <!--... many other things -->
</system.web>
```

The application is running fine I did not get any error but I am not sure this will upgrade .NET framework for my project or not ?

What are the pros and cons ?

Answer (score 3):

The compilation target framework represents the framework that was targeted at the time of compilation.

However, the http runtime target framework is used to make decisions on how we should configure the CLR before loading your application into memory. The target framework of httpruntime can have a lower framework version than the one application was compiled into, in the case where backward compatibility needed or in situation when .NET Framework on server where application is deployed has lower version installed.

Ideally it won't break anything if you directly change the target framework to a higher version than existing in web.config. But check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.6.2-4.7.2) for more details. Also make sure to check if target [.NET framework installed on server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed).

```
<system.web>
   <compilation targetFramework="4.7.2" />
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
</system.web>
```